# Faster Install on a bulk of devices

Tags: google-play-store, apk, side-loading

I am currently faced with installing a large amount of applications on a bulk of devices (100+ at a time).

The biggest issue I am having is the download time of apps and the effect it is having on the WiFi, I am looking for a solution to this, I looked into side-loading via usb but this was just as long to plug in each device and then install the APK individually.

Preferably I need a quick way of installing APKs with minimal interaction as I am using an MDM software that limits my access on the device

Thank you for any answers in advance

Comment: Bulk installation is usually (or should be) a part of MDM: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=canonical&q=Android+MDM+install+apps+silently

Comment: Use one or more own WiFi access points dedicated for this task and place each in a faraday cage. Reduce the max Wifi power or each AP.  Then place just a few devices in each "AP-cage". This eliminates the effect on the normal Wifi system.